# where to put link to applet for all document library edit forms

Tags: 2013, javascript, sharepoint-addin, master-page, edit-form

We are using a javascript / CSOM applet stored in a .js file in websiteobjects. Now we want to show the applet in all **edit forms of document libraries** of the site underneath the metadata.

We don't want to edit the several forms manually because we face 200 libraries.

Where to put it? Master-Page? How and in which section? And how to prevent it being shown in list edit forms?

Answer (score 0):

If your script could check that it should run without a performance hit, you could load it as a [script link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/pnp_powershell/addpnpjavascriptlink) in the site or web. It would run on every page, decide if it's a document library edit form, and then do its thing.

Or yes, you could load it into the master page instead of a script link if you prefer.

Comment: ok, but about masterpage I've asked "How and in which section?" Your statement that I could put it in there does not help much.

Comment: Anywhere not in a content zone, though from a maintenance perspective I greatly prefer the script link approach. Chrome SP Editor that Danny mentions is great, or if you need/prefer a scriptable approach, check out the Add-PnpJavaScriptLink powershell commandlet: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/add-pnpjavascriptlink?view=sharepoint-ps

Answer (score 0):

For easy WYSIWIG adding of **SiteCollection ScriptLinks** use the Chrome SP Editor: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sp-editor/ecblfcmjnbbgaojblcpmjoamegpbodhd?hl=en

Comment: Chrome SP Editor is a great tool, but this doesn't answer anything about the question.